# SHA-256-encrypted string as directory name

Tags: java, path, base64

I need to use a SHA-256-'encrypted' string as a part of a path in a filesystem (ext3, fat, ntfs, ...).

I try to encode it with Base64, but that does not work in all cases, because the Base64-encoded string may contain '/', '\' or other invalid chars.

Is there an (easy) way to get a file-system-safe name of an SHA-256-'encrypted'-string? I do not like to use String.replaceAll() for all possible invalid chars.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: SHA512 is not encryption, but hashing.

Comment: Why can't you just use the SHA256 hash, there are no invalid characters in there are there?

Comment: @HeinAndréGrønnestad A hash is only a set of bits. Are you referring to the hex representation?

Comment: @hexafraction Yes I am. That would be only 0-9 and a-f characters.

Comment: Why not using UUID. It is guaranteed to be unique and it would be shorter than SHA-256.

Comment: @hexafraction Of course I mean hashing. Sorry.

Comment: @Multithreader: Trying to generate some UUID, I get a longer string than a Hex-String of an SHA-256-hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not allowed to write comments ... so I try an answer.

You should really use UUIDs. It must not be longer than an SHA-hash. If so, you have IMHO done something wrong.

Comment: You are right. I have done some mistake. Currently I am using UUIDs because I need them also for a different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

try something like

https://gist.github.com/avilches/750151

```
import java.security.*;

public static String hash256(String data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    md.update(data.getBytes());
    return bytesToHex(md.digest());
}

public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    for (byte byt : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((byt & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    return result.toString();
}
```